# Connecting to Go RPC using curl

Tags: curl, go, rpc

I created a RPC server using the basic instructions listed here: https://golang.org/pkg/net/rpc/.  I am building a application that might not be in Go to communicate with a RPC server and was curious how to manually connect to the server using curl or anything else.

I have tried:

```
curl -v -X CONNECT --url localhost:1234/_goRPC
```

but the output I get is:

```
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying ::1...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 1234 (#0)
> CONNECT /_goRPC HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.37.1
> Host: localhost:1234
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
< Date: Tue, 29 Sep 2015 15:04:29 GMT
< Content-Length: 19
<
404 page not found
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

This is mainly more to understand how to connect to it language agnostically, in the future I will most likely be using libraries from whatever language to communicate to the server.

Edit: for the above error, the url is actually localhost:1234/*goRPC*

But the question still remains to how to create a curl request that performs the same functionality as in the link https://golang.org/pkg/net/rpc/ that the client performs. How does the method call and arguments get serialized and placed in the CONNECT request

Comment: The default path is `/_goRPC_`.

Comment: @jimB yeah I was trying to connect using the _goRPC path. Not sure if my curl request is malformed or not however. Thanks!

Comment: your curl request *is* malformed; you're missing the trailing underscore. The go client request looks like: `CONNECT /_goRPC_ HTTP/1.0`

Comment: @JimB Thank you! can't believe that's what I missed. As part of this, is there any resources on how to pass the full RPC request in the body? the method and args etc ...

Comment: The request uses CONNECT, so there is no body or arguments. The best resource is to read the rpc package source. The format is defined by the implementation of rpc.ServerCodec, which takes rpc.Requests and an optional body, and returns rpc.Responses.

Comment: @JimB Sorry I think I didn't pose my question properly. I am looking to essentially create the dialHTTP that a client generally creates as a curl request. Which boils down to how the method and arguments to the method for the RPC call get serialized by the gobEncoder and how that can be represented as a curl request

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90919/discussion-between-jamil-seaidoun-and-jimb).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone wondering, it is easier to use JSONRPC from the rpc/jsonrpc library and the curl request looks like:

```
curl -X CONNECT --url <url>/_goRPC_ -d '{"method":"your rpc method","params":["args"],"id":<some number to represent your request>}'
```